# Monotone increasing set (all of statistics example 1.4)

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, elementary-set-theory

Example 1.4 in *All of Statistics* states:

> Let $\Omega = R$ and let $A_i= [0,1/i)$ for $i=1,2,...$. Then $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i = [0,1)$.

From the text, "if $A_1, A_2...$ is a sequence of sets, then the union of all sets $A_1,A_2,...$ is the set that contains an outcome that is in at least one set $A_i$ (I have converted the notation to plain English to aid my understanding).

So for example 1.4, $A_1, A_2,... = \{[0,1), [0,.5),...\}$. So the union over $A_1,A_2,...$ is the set that contains values that are in at least one of these sets. Wiseman states that $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}=[0,1)$, but surely by the definition of the union, the union could be also be $[0,0.5)$, as these values appear in at least one of $A_1, A_2,...$? On this, the union could also be $[0,0.001)$? Does the union have to be inclusive of **all** values that appear at least once?

I feel like I'm not quite grasping the idea of taking the union across an infinite series of sets. Could somebody point out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Why the union of them is [0,0.5)? $0.8\in A_1$!

Comment: These sequence of sets is monotone decreasing. $A_i\supset A_{i+1}$, and $A_1$ contains all the other sets.

Comment: Ah ok. In the text he doesn’t go through the proof for this (or at least not yet). I’ll find a proof and maybe that will help me understand. Thanks!